# they could not be imported: _sqlite3 ／Python3.6 ／ CentOS6

Tags: python-3.x, centos

**Environment**

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
```

> CentOS release 6.8 (Final)

```
$ which python3.6
```

> /usr/local/bin/python3.6

```
# find /usr/local -name _sqlite3.so
```

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so

```
# yum install sqlite-devel
```

---

**When I usr SQLite3, Error occurred**

> No module named '_sqlite3'

---

**I decided to build it from source again.**

```
# ./configure --enable-shared --prefix=/usr/local LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib" --with-sqlite=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so

# make
```

> Python build finished successfully!
>
> Following modules built successfully but were removed because they
>   could not be imported:
>   _sqlite3

・Why?

Comment: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so` is the Python 2 *Python wrapper* and not the actual SQLite library.

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so` is the Python 2 *Python wrapper module* and not the actual SQLite library. Moreover, `--with-sqlite` should point to the **headers**, not the shared library. Compilation requires the headers, the dynamic library is located at runtime.

Not that you need to use `--with-sqlite` once you installed the `sqlite-devel` headers; those are put in a default location that the Python configure script knows how to find, in `usr/include`. Only if you have headers in a non-default location would you use that option to point to the directory holding the `sqlite3.h` and `sqlite3ext.h` headers.

Once compiled, the `sqlite3` Python module loads the `_sqlite3*.so` extension module (the exact name differs with the exact Python 3 release and platform), and the dynamic loader will find the right `libsqlite3.so` version.

Comment: Why does sqlite import error occur even though a file exists in this location(/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu_failed.so)?

Comment: `x86_64-linux-gnu_failed` doesn't look right there. What does `import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_var('EXT_SUFFIX'))` say is the correct extension for your platform extensions?

Comment: @re1: also, check the dependencies for that library: `ldd /usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpyth‌​on-36m-x86_64-linux-‌​gnu_failed.so` should show resolved libraries and addresses for all entries.

Comment: I tried print(sysconfig.get_config_var('EXT_SUFFIX')).The result is .cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.

Comment: @re1: then that certainly will explain why the other `.so` file is not being loaded. I'm not sure where the `_failed` postfix comes from. I suppose you could try renaming it, but do make a backup first.